# Menu does not collapse when you click on one of the menu items on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, gatsby

Hi All i need some help :)

I working on a Gatsby, React portfolio where i have a problem with The Menu It does not collapse when you click on one of the menu items on Mobile Devices.

The menu is working fine on desktop.

The menu works fine on all devices until I installed the react-scroll package and set it up.

I have tried to search on Google for help and i found some simlare issues but i still dont know to fix the problem. :)

Hope you can help.

There is to Nav components i my project:

This my Project on SandBox:

NavBar.js
https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-and-portfolio-jr9tn?file=/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js

NavbarLinks:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-and-portfolio-jr9tn?file=/src/components/Navbar/NavbarLinks.js

Comment: Both links are broken. Can you provide a sample (or a sandbox) instead of just GitHub links?

Comment: Hi ferran-buireu
I will try to make a React  Sandbox

Comment: Here you Have the links to the SandBox:

Here is a SandBox: NavBar.js https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-and-portfolio-jr9tn?file=/src/components/Navbar/Navbar.js

NavbarLinks: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-and-portfolio-jr9tn?file=/src/components/Navbar/NavbarLinks.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have your CodeSandbox fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-and-portfolio-forked-43thz?file=/src/components/Navbar/NavbarLinks.js

What was happening is that, since you've installed `react-scroll`, the state was never updated when an item was selected so, React's rehydration was never occurring and your menu was never closed. The code is a bit redundant however I've managed to get it to work. What I've added is a simple function passed via props that toggle the menu.

In your `NavBar.js`, instead of:

```
  <Toggle
    navbarOpen={navbarOpen}
    onClick={() => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)}
  >
```

If added a function, since it's not a good practice to trigger effects directly bonded in the components. I've changed it to:

```
  <Toggle navbarOpen={navbarOpen} onClick={toggleMenu}>
```

That toggleMenu function, is a simply function that does the same than your previous one:

```
  const toggleMenu = () => setNavbarOpen(!navbarOpen)
```

Now, you have isolated that piece of functionality and you can reuse it, passing it to your child component (`NavbarLinks`):

```
  {navbarOpen ? (
    <Navbox>
      <NavbarLinks toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
    </Navbox>
  ) : (
    <Navbox open>
      <NavbarLinks toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
    </Navbox>
  )}
```

*Note: this code is redundant, should be refactored to avoid that kind of unnecessary repetition. For example, something like this is much better:*

```
  <Navbox open={navbarOpen}>
    <NavbarLinks toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
  </Navbox>
```

As you can see, you `<NavbarLinks>` have the functionality to toggle the menu in `toggleMenu` function so there you can trigger the function in every click (`onClick`):

```
const NavbarLinks = ({ toggleMenu })=> {
  return (
    <>
      <NavItem
        activeClass="active"
        to="section1"
        spy={true}
        smooth={true}
        duration={1000}
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >
        About
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem
        activeClass="active"
        to="section2"
        spy={true}
        smooth={true}
        duration={1000}
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >
        Test
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem
        activeClass="active"
        to="section3"
        spy={true}
        smooth={true}
        duration={1000}
        onClick={toggleMenu)}
      >
        Gallery
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem to="/page-2">Contact</NavItem>
    </>
  )
}
```

Since you are destructuring `props`, you have the `toggleMenu` function available directly.

Comment: Ferran Buireu 
Thank you so much for helping me, I really appreciate it. It is Working :) 

But Now The Toggle Button Do not Change to Open Icon again Hope it make sense? :) –

Comment: Well, as initial approach, you can go back and use your `Navbox` in the ternary condition

Comment: Ferran sorry but I AM not sure that i understand what you Mean?  What I need to change?

Comment: `{navbarOpen ? ( <Navbox> <NavbarLinks toggleMenu={toggleMenu} /> </Navbox> ) : ( <Navbox open> <NavbarLinks toggleMenu={toggleMenu} /> </Navbox> )}`